# How to select height based on width for Android Spinner

Tags: android, user-interface, android-spinner

I have two spinners. One for `width` and one for `height` and both having two values. i.e

```
width ==> 1280, 800
height ==> 720, 600





spin_width = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_width);
 spin_height = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_height);
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_width = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,             
                R.array.width_array,R.layout.spinner_item);     
   adapter_width.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

 spin_width.setAdapter(adapter_width);
 spin_width.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String width = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
     mWidth = Integer.valueOf(width);
     Log.d(TAG, "Spinner1"+mWidth);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
    });
```

If user selected `1280` from width box the in height box `720` should be selected automatically and also if `800` selected in width, `600` should select in height box. How to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code.. it will be better to modify your code..

Comment: @RameshKumar : PL once again check above post. I added code

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to select 1280 for width and 600 for height simultaneously? If they can only select pairs of 1280x720 and 800x600 maybe one spinner with those two options is enough.

Comment: @Shiv: I have added answer, check this, if you have query let me know..

Answer (score 0):

Following function is what you need

```
private void selectValue(Spinner spinner, String value) {


        for (int i = 0; i < spinner.getCount(); i++) {

            if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equals(value)) {
                spinner.setSelection(i);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Here function accepts `Spinner` which you want to set selected value and second parameter is what value you want select

> Example

you can call

```
selectValue(spinnnerName,"800");
```

Comment: N J : Thanks for ur rply. probably it works let me check

Answer (score 0):

You have array of Width:  R.array.width_array

You probably have array of Height:  R.array.height_array

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_width = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,             
                R.array.width_array,R.layout.spinner_item);     
   adapter_width.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

 spin_width.setAdapter(adapter_width);
 spin_width.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String width = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
     mWidth = Integer.valueOf(width);
     Log.d(TAG, "Spinner1"+mWidth);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
    });
```

TO:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_width = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,             
                R.array.width_array,R.layout.spinner_item);     
   adapter_width.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


//Adapter Height functionality: 
     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_height = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,             
                    R.array.height_array,R.layout.spinner_item);     
       adapter_height.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

 spin_width.setAdapter(adapter_width);

 spin_height.setAdapter(adapter_height); // set Adapter of height on spinner height
 spin_width.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

 @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  spin_height.setSeletion(position);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
    });
```